# Notice: Undefined variable: node in eval() and Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval()

Tags: 7

After upgrading to Drupal 7, I get the following error on my recent log messages:

> Notice: Undefined variable: node in eval() (line 24 of /home/scode/public_html/modules/php/php.module(74) : eval()'d code).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval() (line 24 of /home/scode/public_html/modules/php/php.module(74) : eval()'d code).

The user accessing the page is "Anonymous (not verified)."

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you locate the faulting page, analyse if there's some PHP inserted into this node and post relevant code ? 
Did you also upgraded PHP from 5.2 to 5.3 ?

Comment: If you had a debugger installed...you could just have placed a breakpoint at line 24 of php.module and had figured out very quickly what was going on. Zend Studio + Zend Debugger are your friends (if you have $3xx dollars). I've used them for years and swear by them. Others recommend Eclipse PDT + XDebug, but I don't know how to use that combo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something is trying to run the php_eval() function in php.module. Most likely you have something configured in your site (such as a block) to use the PHP input filter, which evaluates PHP code and prints the output as text. I would check all the blocks you have defined first.

You can also temporarily put a call to debug_print_backtrace() at the top of the php_eval() function and print it's results while browsing your site as an anonymous user to see what exactly is calling that function.

Comment: Thank you. It was a block that has a $node>path code that cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can put if condition with eval print in php.module file.
+if(is_object('?>' . $code)){
    print eval('?>' . $code);
+}

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  Can you expand a little on how this addresses the original problem, especially why a patch to core is needed in this situation?

Comment: It can happen one of these mistake.

Comment: It can happen one of these mistake. * If you use some server memory allocate function or module * Remove module without uninstall(And called those module set variable etc.) * Uncompleted core or module updates etc. You can check it use "debug_print_backtrace()" & or backend recent log messages. Want check one by one.